# PUT request from React to mongodb with Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, axios

I need some little help. PUT request doesn't work when I send it from React app using Axios. But when I test PUT api from Postman - it works as it suppose to. Server side - node+mongoose+mongodb.

```
modifyCurrentHaspInfo = (e) => { 
      if (prompt("Enter password:") === "123456") {
        axios.put("/hasp/change", {
          data: {
            _id: "5cd40f6f1e922c236caa82f4",
            serial: "11111-22222",
            soft: "test-put"
            }            
          })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);      
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
      } else {
        alert("Wrong password!");
      }         
   }
```

When it finds correct id - data in body must be changed. Here is code from server:

```
//PUT request
app.put("/hasp/change", function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body);
    HaspInfo.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, {$set:req.body}, {new: true}, function(err, hasps) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({error: "Could not modify hasp info..."});
        } else {           
           //console.log(hasps);
           res.status(200).send(hasps);
        }
    }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your axios is *malformed* (not what you're expecting at the backend).

The way you're sending data now from axios can be accessed at the backend as

```
req.body.data

// which will be an object like
{
  _id: "5cd40f6f1e922c236caa82f4",
  serial: "11111-22222",
  soft: "test-put"
}
```

So `_id` can be accessed like `req.body.data._id`. Change your request to one of the following (note the differences)

```
axios.put("/hasp/change", {
  _id: "5cd40f6f1e922c236caa82f4",
  serial: "11111-22222",
  soft: "test-put"
})
```

Or

```
axios.put({
  url: "/hasp/change",
  data: {
    _id: "5cd40f6f1e922c236caa82f4",
    serial: "11111-22222",
    soft: "test-put"
  }            
})
```